# How to solve Relay access denied error in Postfix

Tags: server, email, postfix, mail

By seeing the mail.log, I see errors like this constantly:

```
Dec 15 22:11:49 zeus postfix/smtpd[17078]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[163.247.55.22]: 454 4.7.1 <admin@relojelectronico.cl>: Relay access denied; from=<control_asistencia@mintrab.gob.cl> to=<admin@relojelectronico.cl> proto=ESMTP helo=<MSEX01-SRV.MINTRAB.MS>
```

That is a valid e-mail.Origin domain is `mintrab.gob.cl` and destination is this server, `mail.relojelectronico.cl`.

In `main.cf` file, I have:

> mydestination = $myhostname, zeus.example.com, localhost.example.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost
> relay_domains = $mydestination

This is an Ubuntu 20.04 system with multiple domains controlled by cPanel.

Thanks